# JUnit Selenium Multisite Testing

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have researched and looked around a few forums but I cannot find what I am looking for. I am using Selenium WebDriver.

I am creating JUnit/Selenium tests for a set of 5 sites. Many of the same tests need to be run for each site. These tests are not different from site to site (with the exception of a few), but the data used between different sites is different. Sometimes, the data input to a test is only used in that one test. However, sometimes this data is universal and is used for multiple tests. But, through it all, this universal data is specific to one site.

For instance, I have a Selenium test that tests the login functionality. Each login functionality (eg. Selenium test) works exactly the same way for each site, but I need different logins for each site. At the same time, I need that login for another test within the same site, for example, testing a rewards program or to test their account information on their profile. I looked at parameterized tests, but I don't want to repeat the same array of logins each time I create a test case. I want to save those logins in a properties file somewhere and when the test is running for a specific site, I want the appropriate login used. Besides, I'm already using parameterized tests to repeat a test with different data for the same site (which would be multiplied by 5 times since it has to run for each site in my multisite configuration).

Anybody have some recommendations on what I need to do?

Comment: This is a little unclear on what you are doing. But have a look at `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` in [tag:JUnit4]; hopefully that will get you started.

Comment: I know my question is a bit verbose. To simplify, I want to set up a multisite JUnit/Selenium test which can accept parameters (such as logins, one login for each site) from one central location, without me having to code each site's login in each file.

Comment: So like a resource file? What is this "one central location"?

Comment: Yes. I would like to set this in a properties file, let's say in the main folder.

Comment: So I don't understand what is the problem. Googling "Java configuration file" has 4.4 MILLION hits. Did you try at least one of those?